# How to make custom link /url in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

Suppose my link is

`http://mysite.com/page=id1&like=id2`
now i want to input this in WeBrowser1.Navigate() custom such as,
WeBrowser1.Navigate("http://mysite.com/page=31&like=47")

where id1 ,id2 can get from TextBox1,TextBox2

Answer (score 0):

`Webbrowser.Navigate` takes a string. Therefore, just try something along the lines of:

```
Dim txt1 = TextBox1.Text
Dim txt2 = TextBox2.Text

Webbrowser.Navigate("http://mysite.com/page=" + txt1 + "&like=" + txt2)
```